# Trouble reading in Tokens in C

Tags: c

I can't seem to figure out, how to correctly read in a .txt file that has the following appereance: (example)

```
+ 1
+ 2
- 2
+ 5
p -1
? 5
```

and so on...
what I need now is to store the operator / token which can be '+' '-' 'p' or something like that, and the int that follows in **two different variables** because I need to check them later on.

```
char oprtr[1];
int value;
FILE *fp = fopen(args[1], "r");

while(!feof(fp) && !ferror(fp)){
    if(fscanf(fp, "%s %d\n", oprtr, &value) < 1){
        printf("fscanf error\n");
    }
    if(strcmp(oprtr, "+") == 0){
        function1(bst, value);

    } else if(strcmp(oprtr, "-") == 0){
        function2(bst, value);

    } else if((strcmp(oprtr, "p") == 0) && value == -1){
        function3(root);
    //some other functions and so on...
    }
```

printing out oprtr and value in the loop shows that they are not being red in correctly, but it does compile. Does someone have a solution?

Comment: Your usage of `feof()` is wrong, it doesn't work like that. You can only use it *once I/O has failed* to figure out if it failed due to reaching EOF. You can't use it to predict the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have single characters, you can use `==` to compare them instead of `strcmp`. Just read the input in pairs and use a `switch` for example.

```
char c;
int x;

while(fscanf(fp, "%c %d", &c, &x) == 2)
{   switch(c)
    {   case '+': /* ... */
    }
}
```

Comment: This is better than the OP's code, but will become confused if a line has three tokens for instance. There's nothing inherent in the `fscanf()` call that says "read *lines* formatted like this".

Comment: I'm assuming the input is well-formatted but you're right. In general, the input can be anything and some more sophisticated parsing needs to be done.

Comment: I don't think that this would work as expected. Wouldn't `%c` gobble up the `\n` character in the second iteration?

Comment: didn't try it, but you can add `\n` to the end of `fscanf` if that happens.

Comment: since my input is standardised as I mentioned in the first post "%c %d\n" is the way to go!

Answer (score 1):

Your string `oprtr` is too small to hold anything but an empty string (remember that C strings need a terminating 0 character!). So:

```
char oprtr[1];
```

needs to be at least:

```
char oprtr[2];         // string of maximum size 1
```

or more defensively:

```
char oprtr[256];       // string of maximum size 255
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the fscanf function, you can get the input from the file.

```
int fscanf(FILE *stream, const char *format, ...);

fscanf(fp," %c %d",&c,&d);
```